# How to create QBO BillPayment

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I am converting some V2 Desktop code to V3 online.  I am having trouble with what was a ReceivePaymentAdd in V2.   I looked at the conversion guide and it says to make the ReceivePaymentAdd a BillPayment.  I tried but do not see how to add the AR reference and the customer reference.  Do I create a Payment object then link the BillPayment somehow?

Here is the C++ V2 code I need to convert to C# V3.  Thanks for any help!

```
CQBXface::ReceivePaymentAdd* pTrx = &QB.m_RecvPmtAdd;
pTrx->CustomerRef.sFullName = customerName;
pTrx->ARAccountRef.sFullName = acctName;
pTrx->DepositToAccountRef.sFullName = depositName;
pTrx->PaymentMethodRef.sFullName = payMethodName;
pTrx->sMemo = memo;
pTrx->sRefNumber = documentNum;
pTrx->sTotalAmount = amount;
pTrx->sTxnDate = transDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the conversion guide really says that a v2 `ReceivePayment` is equivalent to a v3 `BillPayment`, then it is *incorrect*.

But, looking at the [migration guide](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0058_faq/qbo_v2_to_v3_migration_guide) that's not what it says...

A `Payment` in v2 is equivalent to a `Payment` in v3. `BillPayment` is a completely separate and unrelated type of transaction.

Comment: I think I found what you're looking at - the SDK to v3 migration guide here: https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0058_faq/qbo_xml_sdk_(soap)_to_v3_rest_migration   It is indeed incorrect - I have already reported the documentation errors to Intuit.

Comment: Yes that is what I was looking at.  So until this is fixed, is a ReceivePaymentAdd a Payment in V3.  Thank you for the help.